# Parse JSON from Jenkins, once hash, then nil

Tags: ruby, json, jenkins, httparty

Jenkins gives me JSON from http://jenkins.net/jobs/MyJob/lastBuild/api/json

Then I use HTTParty to get it like so:

```
response = self.get( url, options )
change = response['changeSet']['items'][0]
```

This gives me the content of the last changes. change.class returns "Hash".
If I try this:

```
change = response['changeSet']['items'][0]['revision']
```

as looking at the JSON suggests, I get "Undefined method '[]' on NilObject".

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT3:

Of course, the problem lies between User and keyboard. The method was first called on another JSON, because it's polling the changes for more than one project, and one of the returned JSON objects didn't contain those keys. D'oh!
Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

If you get that kind of error you're hitting an empty key and then trying to use it as if it's populated. Without seeing what your JSON is, it's hard to say, but one of those is failing. You'll want to inspect these:

```
response['changeSet']
response['changeSet']['items']
response['changeSet']['items'][0]
```

If any of those end up being `nil` then you can pin-point the problem. JSON comes back as an arbitrary structure so chaining a bunch of calls together without any sort of testing can lead to trouble.

Comment: response['changeSet']['items'][0].class
returns 'Hash', so that is fine. Also the contents can be displayed. But if I try to go "deeper" the mentioned error comes up.

Comment: If that's a `Hash`, then it's not `nil` and it should work. Are you sure you're debugging the one with the problem? You might be looking at a valid record and later in a loop you're dealing with an invalid one.

Comment: Another odd thing is it should be an `Array` based on your JSON. Something isn't right. Try assigning `h = response['changeSet']['items'][0]` and then test the results of `h.inspect`.

Comment: It get's weirder. If I do the same thing with irb, it works just fine, but within my Sinatra app, it doesn't.

Comment: ...and it starts pissing me off. inspect prints exactly what I expect, even within the sinatra app. But trying to access the hash in items[0] still says it's Nil, even though it's a hash. What gives?

Comment: Are you sure you're referring to the same object? Many a time a developer has gone nearly mad trying to debug something only to realize they're debugging the wrong instance of the same kind of object. You could try `raise response.inspect unless (response['changeSet']['items'][0])` to deliberately blow up on strange requests.